# Handle notifications from Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I tried to learn about Firebase. And I successfully received notification from it. But how I can open another activity when click on the notification?

This my code:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d("msg", "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new  NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());



}
```

Comment: Are you sending notification from Firebase console? You need to use Data messages

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase FCM notifications click\_action payload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407366/firebase-fcm-notifications-click-action-payload)

Comment: as you like, i find the solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a PendingIntent and notify using NotificationManager

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.your_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
```

As Tosin suggested, if you're sending push notification from Firebase console, you need to put your payload into `data` key

Answer (score 0):

It's sth about notification, nothing to do firebase.

[check this](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#action) you need to Define the Notification's Action