# Firebase push notification goes to wrong page if app is backgrounded

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created app that sends push notification. Everything is working well. If the app is running or not closed it takes me to the second page directly. But problem is that after running my app if I put my app in background or close it and then send notification. After clicking on notification it takes me to the mainpage instead of the second page. I want it must take me to second page even if app is closed or in the background.
Below is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG="MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button BtnshowToken=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonshowtoken);
        BtnshowToken.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String token= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
                Log.d(TAG,"Token: "+token);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }


}
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseInsIDService";

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {

        //get updated token
        String refreshedToken= FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG,"New Token: "+refreshedToken);



    }
}


MyFirebaseMessagingService.java
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService{
    private static final String TAG="MyFirebaseMsgService";


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
       Log.d(TAG, "FROM:" +remoteMessage.getFrom());

        //Check if msg contains data
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: "+remoteMessage.getData());
        }


        //Check if msg contains notification
        if(remoteMessage.getNotification()!=null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Message body: "+remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

        //Display notification
private void  sendNotification(String body){

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0/*Request code*/, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //Set sound of notification
    Uri notificationsound= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationsound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0/*Id of notification*/,notifiBuilder.build());



    }
}


SecondActivity.java
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

     TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);


    }
}


activity_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">





    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="151dp"
        android:src="@drawable/firebase"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Token"
        android:id="@+id/buttonshowtoken"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


second.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:text="Second Activity"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/welcome"
        />

</LinearLayout>


AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abc.firebasenoteg" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="YourActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />


            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />


            </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>

</manifest>


google-services.json
{

  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "785125209715",
    "firebase_url": "https://fir-notification-a5fce.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "fir-notification-a5fce",
    "storage_bucket": "fir-notification-a5fce.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:785125209715:android:676ef33a2e673fd3",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.example.abc.firebasenoteg"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "785125209715-496loih2csg0egp7h9hphtiaui49coeb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyCdvlwxewCNStJwTwcqq3CGBGZ08j9MVdU"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }



    }
  ],


  "configuration_version": "1",



}
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to ClickListener from server request and add listener name in your manifest intent-action inside your activity.

```
"notification" : {
"body" : "Body",
"title" : "Titme",
"icon" : "YourIcon"
"click_action" : "<<yourkey e.g. MainActivity>>"
}

<activity
     android:name=".MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="<<yourkey e.g. MainActivity>>" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```

This is for when your app is not available in foreground.
Hope this is helpful, thanks

Comment: Its not working when i close my app.I am able to go to second page directly if app is running.But if i close my app and then click on notification it opens mainpage not secondpage

Comment: notification json which you have set in your server side, how can you test push notification?

Comment: I  havent set anything on server side.Can u tell me in brief wat u saying exactly.

Comment: It very simple you need to set push request in your server side also set click_action. follow this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37531595/2176952

Comment: I have added that google-services file in question see above.Is that u were asking for?

Comment: this is for configuration, do you konw about json request in firebase

Comment: No I dont know about it.

Comment: Thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Nice answer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the app is in background and you click the notification, the data is stored in extras of the intent. So what you need is something like *action_code* in the firebase request. This is the example :

**Firebase Request :**

```
{
  "to": "/topics/order",
  "priority": "high",
  "notification": {
    "title": "Hello admin",
    "body":"There's new order :)",
    "sound":"default"
  },
  "data": {
    "msgCode":"newOrder"
  }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if (intent.hasExtra("msgCode")) {
    String msgCode = intent.getStringExtra("msgCode");
    if (msgCode.equals("newOrder")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "newOrder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("zihad", "newOrder");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ListOrderActivity.class));
        intent.removeExtra("msgCode");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where  that Firebase Request portion implemented and how?

Comment: how did you push notification from your firebase?

Comment: I clicked on Notifications and then new message and then send gave message ,selected app i.e my package name and then clicked on send message.

Comment: "notification" : {
"body" : "Body",
"title" : "Titme",
"icon" : "YourIcon"
"click_action" : "<<yourkey e.g. MainActivity>>"
} where to write this part?

Comment: So what you have to do is to push notif from firebase's API.. So it's gona be like [this](http://prnt.sc/eewph3)