# Firebase Messaging: Activity from onMessageReceived doesn't open

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase Notification works perfect. I get the notifications, but I have a problem. I want to open a specific activity after clicking on the notification. If the app is open, it works perfect. But if the app is closed, the MainActivity opens. I don't know why. Can somebody help me. What must I change? Thanks!

Here's the code of onMessageReceived:

```
public class MessageService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,activity2.class); //To this activity it should also go when the app isn't open

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("App");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0,notificationBuilder.build());


}
}
```

---

**EDIT**

WelcomeActivity (launcher activity):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("type")) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("type",getIntent().getStringExtra("type"));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the application is closed or is in background the data from the notification arrives at your launcher activity in the intent. You can put a check in oncreate() that if your intent has data then open desired activity otherwise simple opens launcher activity or main activity whatever be your launcher activity.

Comment: That means that I always send other data with the notification?

Comment: no the notification contains the flags or the specified data type with which you can distinguish the notification. by putting that notification in check you can do your further implementation...

Comment: Can you show me the code how you mean this, please?

Comment: Where I must write this code? In onMessageReceived?

Comment: Put this code in oncreate method of your launcher activity which opens very first when application is opened

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work. Do you maybe know what can be my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: I write my code in my question. Can you check it please?

Comment: the code in your question can only be called when your application is in foreground not in case when app is in background or closed

Comment: Yes, I write the code I have now with your news in the Edit and then tell me please whats wrong.

Comment: sir further code will be written in the launcher activity of your project from where data arrives atfirst when push arrives

Comment: Now I added the code from hastebin.com/ezisigadux.scala you gave me in the Welcome Activity. But it doesn't work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: WelcomeActivity is my launcher activity

Comment: in my suggestion the "type" is the parameter in which i am passing data which help me to distinguish the type of push... you have to debug the push data and then perform the function

Comment: I don't really understand. Can you show me a code how you intend it? Then your answer gets the check!

Comment: go to your firebase console and create a push to you  application, and in the additional properties add some data with key-"title" and data whatever you want then debug the code from here in the welcome activity... basically the type is the key of data you are sending from the backend or firebase console

Comment: THANKS! That works! Very nice. I check your answer! Thanks very much

Comment: are you satisfied with answer.. what was the problem.

Comment: I'm very satisfied. My problem was that I didn't send the data with the notification.

Comment: Thanks you too :)

Answer (score 0):

> **Notification messages delivered when your app is in the background:** 
>   In this case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

One approach is to add the 'click_action' flag which will tell the system which activity to open when the user clicks on the notification. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/37656244/3482621

Also see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support