# Firebase click_action in notification payload work fine but it causes second time to launch same activity specified in click_action

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was study about Firebase's `click_action` use to open activity on notification click when app was killed. It's work fine! But after closing app open app normally`(Not from notification)` but its open same activity as specified in `click_action`.

Here is the code in manifest for launch screen :

```
<activity
    android:name=".activity.SplashScreen"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/LoginScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And for Firebase notification :

```
<activity android:name=".activity.RequestsActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="RequestsActivity" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Code for Application exit when get back to home screen then :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Flow of current screen

**Notification->Click->RequestActivity->Back_Click->HomeScreen->BackClick->Exit_App->Reopen_App->RequestActivity(But it must be HomeScreen!).**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37656244/1318946